# Get SOAP response data in variables PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to SOAP and XML in PHP. I have the following result from SOAP processed using WSDL and now looking to get the response data in variables to be sent to database and use it for further processing. Tried all possible permutation and combination

Used the following to get the info from the server.

```
$request = $client->__soapCall("<function Name>", $args);
```

Following is the response received from server

```
array (size=10)
  'pWeoMotPolicyIn_inout' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'vehicleTypeCode' => string '22' (length=2)
      public 'vehicleSubtype' => string 'LXI' (length=3)
      public 'elecAccTotal' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'addLoadingOn' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'nonElecAccTotal' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'polType' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'registrationNo' => string '<some value>' (length=10)
      public 'partnerType' => string 'p' (length=1)
      public 'ncb' => string '20' (length=2)
      public 'prvClaimStatus' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'registrationDate' => string '19-Oct-2013' (length=11)
      public 'miscVehType' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'fuel' => string 'P' (length=1)
      public 'chassisNo' => string 'ABCD' (length=6)
      public 'contractId' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'yearManf' => string '2013' (length=4)
      public 'spDiscRate' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'cubicCapacity' => string '1298' (length=4)
      public 'regiLocOther' => string '<some value>' (length=5)
      public 'addLoading' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'vehicleSubtypeCode' => string '21' (length=2)
      public 'prvPolicyRef' => string '123123123' (length=9)
      public 'vehicleMake' => string '<some value>' (length=6)
      public 'autoMembership' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'termStartDate' => string '24-Oct-2014' (length=11)
      public 'carryingCapacity' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'termEndDate' => string '23-Oct-2015' (length=11)
      public 'hypo' => string '<some value>' (length=19)
      public 'branchCode' => string '1104' (length=4)
      public 'prvNcb' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'vehicleMakeCode' => string '110' (length=3)
      public 'vehicleIdv' => string '325236' (length=6)
      public 'prvInsCompany' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'engineNo' => string 'ABCD' (length=4)
      public 'product4digitCode' => string '1801' (length=4)
      public 'color' => string 'RED' (length=3)
      public 'vehicleModel' => string '<some value>' (length=5)
      public 'vehicleType' => string 'Private Car' (length=11)
      public 'prvExpiryDate' => string '13-Nov-2014' (length=11)
      public 'tpFinType' => null
      public 'deptCode' => string '18' (length=2)
      public 'vehicleModelCode' => string '29' (length=2)
      public 'registrationLocation' => string '<some value>' (length=5)
      public 'zone' => string 'A' (length=1)
  'accessoriesList_inout' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
  'paddoncoverList_inout' => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'WeoMotGenParamUser' => 
        array (size=13)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[5]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[7]
              ...
          3 => 
            object(stdClass)[8]
              ...
          4 => 
            object(stdClass)[9]
              ...
          5 => 
            object(stdClass)[10]
              ...
          6 => 
            object(stdClass)[11]
              ...
          7 => 
            object(stdClass)[12]
              ...
          8 => 
            object(stdClass)[13]
              ...
          9 => 
            object(stdClass)[14]
              ...
          10 => 
            object(stdClass)[15]
              ...
          11 => 
            object(stdClass)[16]
              ...
          12 => 
            object(stdClass)[17]
              ...
  'pQuestList_inout' => 
    object(stdClass)[18]
  'pDetariffObj_inout' => 
    object(stdClass)[19]
      public 'driverQualificationCode' => null
      public 'vehPurchaseType' => null
      public 'extCol25' => null
      public 'extCol26' => null
      public 'tacMakeCode' => null
      public 'extCol23' => null
      public 'extCol24' => null
      public 'extCol29' => null
      public 'extCol27' => null
      public 'extCol28' => null
      public 'extCol33' => null
      public 'extCol32' => null
      public 'extCol31' => null
      public 'extCol30' => null
      public 'registrationAuth' => null
      public 'extCol12' => null
      public 'extCol13' => null
      public 'extCol14' => null
      public 'extCol15' => null
      public 'extCol16' => null
      public 'extCol17' => null
      public 'extCol18' => null
      public 'extCol19' => null
      public 'otherGoodsFrequency' => null
      public 'extCol20' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'extCol22' => null
      public 'incurredClmExpCode' => null
      public 'extCol21' => null
      public 'clmHistCode' => null
      public 'roadType' => null
      public 'bodyType' => null
      public 'monthOfMfg' => null
      public 'natureOfGoods' => null
      public 'extCol9' => null
      public 'extCol8' => null
      public 'extCol7' => null
      public 'extCol6' => null
      public 'vehPurchaseDate' => null
      public 'extCol5' => null
      public 'extCol4' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'vehDrivenBy' => null
      public 'extCol3' => null
      public 'extCol2' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'extCol1' => string '3.283' (length=5)
      public 'goodsTransType' => null
      public 'permitType' => null
      public 'extCol38' => null
      public 'extCol39' => null
      public 'extCol34' => null
      public 'extCol35' => null
      public 'extCol36' => null
      public 'extCol10' => null
      public 'extCol37' => null
      public 'extCol11' => null
      public 'extCol40' => null
      public 'driverExperience' => null
  'premiumDetailsOut_out' => 
    object(stdClass)[20]
      public 'serviceTax' => string '1197' (length=4)
      public 'collPremium' => string '11207' (length=5)
      public 'totalActPremium' => string '1432' (length=4)
      public 'netPremium' => string '9974' (length=4)
      public 'totalIev' => string '325236' (length=6)
      public 'addLoadPrem' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'totalNetPremium' => string '36' (length=2)
      public 'imtOut' => string '22,' (length=3)
      public 'totalPremium' => string '9974' (length=4)
      public 'ncbAmt' => string '-2135.499576' (length=12)
      public 'stampDuty' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'totalOdPremium' => string '8542' (length=4)
      public 'spDisc' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'finalPremium' => string '11207' (length=5)
  'premiumSummeryList_out' => 
    object(stdClass)[21]
      public 'WeoMotPremiumSummaryUser' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[22]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[23]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[24]
              ...
          3 => 
            object(stdClass)[25]
              ...
  'pError_out' => 
    object(stdClass)[26]
  'pErrorCode_out' => string '0' (length=1)
  'pTransactionId_inout' => string '<some value>' (length=8)
```

Looking forward how to get the above response values in variable. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution to this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the array $request

You can iterate through that array and save each index into a php variable.

For a better look at the array structure, print_r($request) in the client code and see the keys and values to iterate.

Good luck.